# jquery for night mode and day mode with buttons

Tags: jquery, css, button, click

I want to add two buttons in the HTML page day mode and night mode and the result should be when day mode pressed then it should have white background along with black color text and in night mode dark background along with white text I tried but not successful can someone help

```js
function dark() {
  $("#dark").click(function() {
    $('body').addClass('night');
    $('div').addClass('night');
    $('li').addClass('night');
  });
};

function day() {
  $("#day").click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('night');
    $('div').removeClass('night');
    $('li').removeClass('night');
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="day" onclick="day();">Day Mode</button>
<button id="dark" onclick="dark();">Night Mode</button>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `onclick` and the functions if you are going to use jQuery click listeners. Otherwise you will have to click button twice before the jQuery listener fires from inside the functions

Comment: Can you also add the `css` for class `night` that you have used which did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this :

```js
function theme(color){
      $('body').attr('class',color);
}
```

```css
.day {
  background: white;
  color:black;
}

.dark{
  background: black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="theme('day');">Day Mode</button>
<button onclick="theme('dark');">Night Mode</button>


<br><br>
<span>Some text !!</span>
```